# Where to find consensus forward estimates from the past?

Tags: equities, market-data

I need to find the market consensus estimate values (Revenue, EBITDA, Net Income, Free Cash Flow) since 2018 for a set of publicly-traded American companies. The thing is, I can find the present market consensus numbers but there seems not to be an aggregation of historical market consensus numbers anywhere.

The end goal is to calculate how some forward multiples (like Price-to-Earnings) have evolved over time, however for that purpose I need to know -for example- what the 2019 and 2020 expected revenue for a company was in early 2018, etc.

Comment: Try I/B/E/S (now part of Refinitiv) https://www.refinitiv.com/en/financial-data/company-data/ibes-estimates

Comment: Yep, that’s a nice source IMO @DimitriVulis

Comment: Thank you both @DimitriVulis and Kermittfrog.